# Wheel Positioning - Camber and Toe

Tags: tires, suspension, wheels, alignment

I have a baseline of information regarding camber and toe.

Why would I add more or less camber to my wheel unless I'm a NASCAR drivier making only left hand turns and want better traction for that act?

If I had too much negative camber wouldn't I just wear out the inside of my tire very quickly?

How much camber is typically applied to a production vehicle and why?

Under what circumstances would I have toe in or out on my front or rear wheels?  Wouldn't this, as well, increase my tire wear if adjusted to extremely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negative camber contributes to stability. The more negative camber there is, within limits, the less a car will wander at high speed. The downside of too much negative camber is tire wear. In a production vehicle camber is usually between -0.75 to -3 degrees. Just enough to give stability on the highway without too much tire wear.

Toe contribute the most to tire wear. The best position for toe is zero to prevent tire wear. This zero toe needs to be maintained during the most common operation of the vehicle or while driving forward under light power. Front wheel drive cars are slightly towed out. What this accomplishes is that when the front wheel apply power the suspension flexes forward the suspension bushings flex the toe tends to zero. Rear wheel drive cars tend to be toed in slightly. This way when the rear wheels apply power the fronts will drag slightly causing the bushings to flex back again reducing the toe to zero.

Comment: Every Honda since the 1970's has a slight toe in spec. Toe out results in unstable steering on some roads conditions, such as ruts. We used to change the settings on the toe out cars to toe in because of customer complaints.